# Select a result when left join only joins on some rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to implement a business validation rule that checks the contents of 2 tables. The rule has 3 parts:

1. If all the rows in table1 match a row in table 2 then it should pass validation
2. If all of the rows in table1 do not match a row in table2 then it should pass.
3. If some of the rows in table1 join to table2 and others don't then it should fail.

I've added three datasets below to show when it should pass and fail

Dataset 1 (this should pass):

```
Table1
ID   Other Column
1    xxxx
2    xxxx
3    xxxx
4    xxxx

Table2
ID    FK   OtherColumn
1     1    xxxx
2     2    xxxx
3     3    xxxx
4     4    xxxx
```

Dataset 2 (This should pass):

```
Table1
ID   Other Column
1    xxxx
2    xxxx
3    xxxx
4    xxxx

Table2
ID    FK   OtherColumn
1     5    xxxx
2     6    xxxx
3     7    xxxx
4     8    xxxx
```

Dataset 3 (This should fail because ID 2 and 3 in table1 don't match any FK in Table2):

```
Table1
ID   Other Column
1    xxxx
2    xxxx
3    xxxx
4    xxxx

Table2
ID    FK   OtherColumn
1     1    xxxx
2     5    xxxx
3     6    xxxx
4     4    xxxx
```

You can join the two tables by doing the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ID = Table2.FK
```

`Table2` will have 0 or 1 record for each record in `Table1`

So far the only way I have worked out how to do this is by doing to selects and comparing the number of rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(Table1.ID)
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ID = Table2.FK
```

And compare with

```
SELECT COUNT(Table1.ID)
FROM Table1
```

I think it works, but it feels like there should be an easier way to do this.

If it makes a difference, the database is Microsoft SQL 2008

Comment: why do you write out `one` sometimes and `1` other times, but never write out `two`, only `2`

Comment: @vol7ron - Now that you mention and I stop and think about it, I probably do it a lot of the time, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT count(distinct t1.id) as NumInT1, count(distinct t2.fk) as NumInT2andT1
FROM Table1 t1 left join
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.ID = t2.FK;
```

If you know that `Table2` has no duplicate values of `FK`, you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT count(t1.id) as NumInT1, count(t2.fk) as NumInT2andT1
FROM Table1 t1 left join
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.ID = t2.FK;
```

You test passes when `NumInT2andT1` is equal to `NumInT1` or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this fail? Because the ID 4 match, and it's the only one which matchs

```
Dataset 2 (This should pass):

Table1
ID   Other Column
1    xxxx
2    xxxx
3    xxxx
4    xxxx

Table2
ID    FK   OtherColumn
1     4    xxxx
2     5    xxxx
3     6    xxxx
4     7    xxxx
```

Ok, anyway may be you can control it by the COUNT of the rows. I'll make a pseudo code that you can use in a procedure or a trigger

```
DECLARE @matchRows int;
DECLARE @normalRows int;

SELECT @matchRows=COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.FK

SELECT @normalRows=COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 t1

IF(@matchRows>0)
BEGIN
     IF(@matchRows<@normalRows)
     BEGIN
          -Here your code in case of fail!
     END
END
```

You may be can do

```
DECLARE @booleanControl BIT;

SELECT @booleanControl = CAST(
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT *
                    FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.KF
                    WHERE COUNT(t1.ID) = COUNT(t2.FK) OR COUNT(t2.FK) = 0
                    ) THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
   END 
   AS BIT)
```

When this booleanControl returns TRUE he can pass, otherway he doesn't

Comment: Your right about dataset 2. Sorry, I stuffed up the test data. See latest edit. Your pseudocode is essentially what I'm doing now. I was looking for a better way of doing it.

Comment: Ok, see if the new answer can help you